# How to avoid Miscellaneous channel category in android FCM Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, channel

How can I delete miscellaneous channel?
[image]

It's created by fcm. I use flutter_local_notifications packege to create channel and change notifications settings. But some android devices (samsung S10, android 12) receive notifications by miscellaneous channel and I dont want this.

Answer (score 0):

I found.

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="default_notification_channel_id" />`

Firstly, I have added this. But It didn't work. Then, I moved it to below **activity** and created new channel with same id. So, miscellaneous is deleted.